# STM32F407 Debugging via JTAG: STICKYERR issue with DHCSR register access

Tags: debugging, arm, stm32, jtag

I am playing with debugging `STM32F407` via JTAG protocol and DAP interface etc. I want to use the `DHCSR` register to stop the processor (set the `C_HALT` bit in this register). And to do this through the interface DAP need to configure the register `CSW`, write the address of `DHCSR` in the register `TAR` and the necessary data in the register `DRW`, all this I do but after all this procedure I constantly get an error `STICKYERR` in the DAP register `CTRL/STAT` and accordingly can not read the register `DHCSR` or write to it. What I do wrong?

I attempted to halt the STM32F407 processor using the `DHCSR` register via the JTAG protocol and DAP interface. My steps:

- Write `0b1010` (the `DPACC` register code) into the `IR` register.
- Some settings in the `AP` register `CSW` need to be configured. To access this register, we need to select the corresponding `AP` and register bank in the `DP SELECT` register. Write to the `DR` register:

  - DATA[31:0] = `0x00`

    - APSEL[31:24] = `0x00`
    - APBANKSEL[7:4] = `0x00`
  - A[3:2] = `0b10` (address of `SELECT` register)
  - RnW = `0b0`
- Next, we need to write the `CSW` register. Since this is an `AP` register, we need to use the `APACC` register to access it:

  - Write `0b1011` (the `APACC` register code) into the `IR` register.
- Form the data for the configuration: set the data size for writing to 32-bits (`Size[0:2] = 0b010`), disable the auto-increment function of the address (`AddrInc[5:4] = 0b00`). Write to `DR`:

  - DATA[31:0] = `0x2200 0002` (MasterType=1, Hprot1=1, Size=b010)
  - A[3:2] = `0b00` (address of `CSW` register)
  - RnW = `0b0`
- Then we need to set the address of the memory cell to which we want to write the data. This is done through the `AP` register `TAR`. And since this register belongs to the same `AP` as `CSW` and is in the same bank, we can omit the reference to the `DP SELECT` register and immediately write the address value. Write to `DR`:

  - DATA[31:0] = `0xE000EDF0`
  - A[3:2] = `0b01` (address of `TAR` register)
  - RnW = `0b0`
- The last step is to actually write the data. To do this, we need to write them to the `DRW` register. Write to `DR`W:

  - DATA[31:0] = `0x03`
  - A[3:2] = `0b11` (address of `DRW` register)
  - RnW = `0b0`

After this I got `STICKYERR` in the DAP register `CTRL/STAT.

Comment: You do not mention this in your flow. I'm not certain you did it: You should enable debug (and system) power domains through `CSYSPWRUPREQ` and `CDBGPWRUPREQ` by setting bits 28 and 30 of `CTRL/STAT` prior to any Mem-AP accesses. See [ADIv5 (IHI0031F)](https://documentation-service.arm.com/static/5f900b6cf86e16515cdc0648), page B2-78

Comment: Yes, you absolutely right! I forgot to mention this in my description but I did it and the result is the same - `STICKYERR`.

Comment: If you clear errors through writing ABORT register (write 0x1f in DP address 0) between all accesses, do you still get error all the time ?

Comment: @Nipo Yes. After writing ABORT register I continue getting error.